# Warning. Boot script table modified!!! Please contact vendor. (Lenovo BIOS Issue)

Tags: boot, uefi, suspend, lenovo, bios

I installed Ubuntu and removed Windows 10 from my Lenovo G50-45. Every time I click on "suspend", the screen goes blank and the text appears in yellow:

```
Warning. Boot script table modified!!!
```

It just restarts over again and acts normal but I don't understand why this happens. Any suggestions? I saw a similar question but it is unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

The same happens on my lenovo G 50-45 too. I think disabling the suspend option is the only solution and I have done the same.

Comment: This also happens on my G50-45 but only on the second suspend. I can safely suspend and resume once before it crashes on the second try.

Comment: The same happens in mine too but it is happening specifically on Lenovo G 50 models