# Bootscript table modified. Please Contact Vendor

Tags: suspend, lenovo

When I suspend ubuntu sometimes it is showing error

> "Bootscript table modified. Please Contact Vendor".

I think its showing every alternate time. And after searching through some forums I got to know that this problem is more in lenovo devices (especially g50-45, mine too). I found no answer in any of the forums (even here there are two same questions with no answer). I don't want to disable suspend. I need it to work.
I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: There are multiple people facing this issue, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/651481/boot-script-table-modified-please-contact-vendor and http://askubuntu.com/questions/752907/boot-script-table-modified-please-contact-vendor and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212044

Comment: From the last link, it appears that it's a bug in Lenovo's BIOS.